# EF Core In-Memmory Array mapping

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql, ef-core-2.2

I have a string array column in database

```
ALTER TABLE sample ADD languages VARCHAR[] NULL;
```

which is mapped to model:

```
public string[] languages { get; set; }
```

Using EF Core with PostgreSQL (Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.2.0) works out of the box.

However, when I want to test DbContext using In-Memmory (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 2.2.4) I got this error:

*System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'sample.languages' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'string[]' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.*

So, adding this to model builder configuration solves the In-Memmory error:

```
 builder.Property(p => p.languages)
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => string.Join("'", v),
                        v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

But raises new one (Npgsql):

> Can't cast database type character varying[] to String
>      at Npgsql.NpgsqlDefaultDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 column)

Do you have any hints please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not many databases support array type columns out of the box. Actually PostgreSQL might be the only one from the currently supported databases which does that. According to the original exception, apparently in-memory database also doesn't support it (currently).

EF Core builds a separate model for each database type. Each database provider exposes an extension method of `DatabaseFacade` like `IsSqlServer()`, `IsNpgsql()`, `IsInMemory()` etc. which can be used inside `OnModelCreating` to conditionally configure different mappings for a specific database type(s) if needed.

The intended usage is like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sample>(builder =>
{
    if (!Database.IsNpgsql()) // <--
    {
         builder.Property(p => p.languages)
             .HasConversion(
                 v => string.Join("'", v),
                 v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));    
    }
});
```

If you are using separate classes implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` for configuring the model, then you should pass the `Database` to their constructor and store in a class member, because the `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>` passed to the `Configure` method does not provide such information.

Comment: Any updates for net 5?

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov Nope. Not even for 6 afaik.

Comment: Same issue with .net5, this fix still works. Thanks!